# How to type manipulated object correctly with Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an object where each property value is a different type of function. Each receives the same parameter and returns a different type of object.

```
const initialObj = {
  a: (c: number) => ({ c }),
  b: (c: number) => ({ d: c }),
}
```

I want to create another object from this one. Where the keys are the same and the values are the returned objects.

```
{
  a: { c: 4 };
  b: { d: 4 };
}
```

I tried to type it like this:

```
{ [Key in typeof keyof initialObj]: ReturnType<typeof initialObj[Key]> }
```

With this I get a type like this:

```
{
  a: { c: number } | { d: number };
  b: { c: number } | { d: number };
}
```

What I want to get at the end looks like this:

```
{
  a: { c: number };
  b: { d: number };
}
```

Is this possible? If so how should I type it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your attempt is very close, but `typeof` and `keyof` are switched.

```
type Foo = { [Key in keyof typeof initialObj]: ReturnType<typeof initialObj[Key]> }
```

See this [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmOU4EMA2B5ARgKxgXhgG8AoGGFALhgAphqwBXAWywFMAnASgID5aiMYDAC+XADRkYWanQYt23PgJgATasLGSRJElACeABzYwAYiBAFiMANoBpNvvhgYAa0cgAZjAPGvzpFRMXABdagAlNihGDjAAFSM2AB5fNn8EQPRsHHtHEP4dElU2YDQUDhNQSFhPC2pzEABuXVqQADoUNuASVrasNtUWiw6BmAB6MZhODhAOHuH+4Qmpjhm5oA). It demonstrates that a variable of type `Foo` has the correct semantics. If you're using an older version of typescript this might not work, however.